# Hardcode sign in with email and password firebase in angular

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to authenticate users using my angular webapp without the users needing to sign-up for an account. At first I tried sign in anonymously but that created too many anonymous users. I am thinking about create an user and sign in with hardcoded email and password in my code but that exposes the email and password in the console. Can bad guys do anything with the email and password they find in the console like can they access my database with that via REST API or is there a better way to do this?

My code:

```
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test@email.com","helloworld")
    .then((user) => {
      this.authState = user
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Console:

```
Request URL: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=APIKEY

{email: "test@email.com", password: "helloworld", returnSecureToken: true}
email: "test@email.com"
password: "helloworld"
returnSecureToken: true
```

Comment: @Dharmaraj I am not worrying about man in middle attacks. I am worrying about bad guys are able to extract the hardcoded username and password and do something with it

Comment: They are visible on your own computer only. So unless someone gets physical access to your device they can't see it.

Comment: @Dharmaraj anyone who goes to the webapp will be able to see the hardcoded credentials from the console.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use "Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously" feature of firebase.
You can follow official docs from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth